# What is the use of inheriting object class methods in functional interface eg- toString, equals

Tags: java, object, inheritance, java-8, functional-interface

I found following code, What is use of inherited equals() and toString() method.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface  FunInterface<T> {
   // An  abstract method  declared in the functional interface 
   int test(T  o1,   T  o2);

   // Re-declaration of the equals() method in the Object class 
   boolean equals(Object  obj);

   String toString();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The main reason to (re)declare such a method, is to extend and document the contract. In case of [`Comparator.equals(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), it’s not that obvious, as it doesn’t specify so much news. It says

> This method must obey the general contract of `Object.equals(Object)`. Additionally, this method can return `true` *only* if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator. Thus, `comp1.equals(comp2)` implies that `sgn(comp1.compare(o1, o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2))` for every object reference `o1` and `o2`.

which most people would have assumed anyway. Even worse, not overriding `equals` is fine, if not to say the best way to enforce this contract, especially as the JRE classes never consider comparator equality anyway.

To get better examples of overriding methods, consider

[`List.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

> Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are `equal`. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `Objects.equals(e1, e2)`.)
>
> …

[`List.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--)

> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> ```
> int hashCode = 1;
> for (E e : list)
>     hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
> ```
>
> This ensures that `list1.equals(list2)` implies that `list1.hashCode()==list2.hashCode()` for any two lists, `list1` and `list2`, as required by the general contract of `Object.hashCode()`.

This provides an extended contract that can not be fulfilled by simply using the `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods inherited from `java.lang.Object`. Unfortunately, an interface can not enforce its implementation classes to override these methods, but that shouldn’t stop it from declaring it to document the contract.

---

Of course, having such a contract would not be compatible with an intention of using an interface as *functional interface*, as lambda expressions and method references can not override methods inherited from `java.lang.Object` to provide more specific implementations.

But `java.util.Comparator` was introduced in Java 2, long before Java 8, which introduced the concept of functional interfaces. As said, it’s special in that we still can use `Comparator` as functional interface, as the `equals` implementation inherited from `java.lang.Object` is fine regarding the contract specified for `java.util.Comparator.equals`.

So when designing new interfaces intended to be used as *functional interface*, you should not declare methods matching those of `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: the way you usually answer these is beyond me, still need to work quite a lot on that :(

Answer (score 1):

I see no point in this, since you can't really override them. For example you can override a `default` method to become `abstract`:

```
interface First {
    public default void go() {

    }
}

interface Second extends First {
    @Override
    public void go();
}
```

And any class implementing `Second` will be forced to implement `go`, unless it is of course `abstract` too.

It looks like someone thought about forcing every implementor of `FunInterface` to implement `hashCode/equals` too - but that would not work either.

Comment: Then why java.util.Comparator (i.e. functional interface ) inherited equals() method.

Comment: @RajN believe or not - some people still think that this was a mistake, as the `Comparator` does not need this method at all. It is there just to specify a *specific* `javadoc` regarding `Comparator`s. Also notice that `Collection` has `equals` also - for the same reason (if this is a reason at all)

Comment: @Eugene in case of `Collection`, it’s debatable, but for `List`, `Set`, and `Map`, it’s justified, as that’s the right place to define the contract, even if interfaces can’t enforce the implementors not to use the methods ingerited from `java.lang.Object`. By the way, believe it or not, regarding `Comparator.equals`, there is even an [actual, conforming implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Not that it has much practical relevance.

Comment: I think the equals method in List, Set and other collections have nothing to do with the Objects equals method, although the end purpose might be same they are not overridden methods. Even the Collection interfaces equals documentaion says the same (While the Collection interface adds no stipulations to the general contract for the Object.equals).