# Understanding overriding interface method in sub-interface

Tags: java, collections

I came across `Collection` interface, which [declares `add()` method](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/Set.java#L225) as follows:

```
boolean add(E e);
```

Then I came across `Set` interface, which extends `Collection`, which [declares `add()` method](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#L289) with same above signature.

Since the signatures are same, I suppose `Set` is overriding method in `Collection`. The only difference I can notice is in comments. `Collection` says:

> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element.

`Set` says:

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.

So I feel, technically, we can omit declaration of `add` from `Set` and still the whole Java collections framework would have behaved without any issue, but its there simply because in `Set`, `add()` has different meaning than that in `Collection`. 
**Q1.** Is it so? Or anything else is achieved with overriding `add()` in `Set`?

**Q2.** Is this normal usage pattern across the framework? Does any other interface hierarchy follow the same?

**Q3.** How correct it is to  override method from super interface in sub interface, just because it has different meaning in sub interface, even though it has same signature? (Is it that this is perfectly correct and as expected and I am unnecessarily finding it surprisingly weird because I am facing it for first time?)

Comment: Q1: Yes I believe it's simply to add the better documentation. Q2: yes check out the `List` interface, it also defines the add method with better documentation Q3: It is correct. You aren't defining any implementation so you aren't technically overriding, you are just defining better in the documentation on how the method should be implemented

Comment: Think of it this way, if you were defining your own Set implementation and your own List implementation and all you had was the javadoc on the Collection... would you know exactly how it should behave? The Collection javadoc is more generic, the Set and List javadocs are more specific, because they describe a more specific implementation

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50695623/2711488